# what's the meaning of "live-code approach"?

Tags: meaning

> At the heart of the book is the Deitel signature “live-code approach.”
>   Concepts are presented in the context of complete working programs,
>   rather than in code snippets

What's the meaning of "live-code approach" in the context?

Comment: I think this is probably too localized of a question but FYI I'll answer it anyway:  Programming books are known for showing only a tiny bit of example code (a "code snippet"), often created artificially for the sake of illustrating the example.  The "live-code" approach is the name that [Paul Deitel](http://www.deitel.com/) coined (or at least took over) for his way of showing more complete "real life" examples that use snippets from more realistic working programs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is already in your question.

> Concepts are presented in the context of complete working programs, rather than in code snippets.

It says that the examples presented in the book are complete working programs = live programs, compared to code snippets, which are just chunks of code which doesn't work by itself and therefore is dead.

Live-code approach: complete working program, whole code. Be aware that this is neither a coined phrase, nor a specific coding term. That's why the author had to explain themselves in the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

From this [Deitel](http://www.deitel.com/Books/Java/SmallJavaHowtoProgram6e/PrefaceSmallJavaHowtoProgram/tabid/1805/Default.aspx) page:

> Small Java How to Program, 6/e, is loaded with Live-Code examples—each new concept is presented in the context of a complete, working Java application that is immediately followed by one or more sample executions showing the program’s inputs and outputs.... The book contains 72 complete Live-Code examples consisting of 4917 lines of code

I have not read either the Java or the C++ texts, which seem to be aimed toward Computer Science 101 classes. I am inferring that *Live-Code* gives complete programs that provide more context and utility to the learner.

The opposite of their coined term, *live-code*, would be a code snippet. Since the snippet lacks context, it may be more difficult to know how to apply the concept being 
presented.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the opposite of "live code" here would be "pseudocode" or "code snippets." Probably both.

Answer (score 2):

*Live* here is used to mean:

> **2e.** being in operation (*a live microphone*) [[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/live)]

So the sense of the quoted phrase "*live-code approach*" is exactly as described by the second sentence in the passage.  This is not, to my knowledge, a standard phrase, and the quote marks indicate that the phrase has been invented for this specific purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Live code is a complete program.
If you create a project and paste the live code there, it works.
But, the code snippets is a part of the whole code. 
You need to write the rest of the code in order to run the snippet code.

Comment: Your answer would be greatly improved by references.